# Possible to incrementally increase coverage with jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, code-coverage

Let's say you already have a repo with zero to little testing coverage. If I were to start setting threshold, I would have to spend the next few weeks just adding tests to increase the coverage.

Instead, is it possible to request that *each* PR has to always *increase* the coverage, even if by a ~0.01%? Otherwise, if it's a decrease, then the coverage report should fail, basically saying "Merging this PR will decrease the overall coverage".

Is this possible with `jest`?

Comment: Well i don't think it's possible unless your write a script by yourself and run in pre-commit hook, which does read the overall coverage from a file and compare with the current one with the last one, and update file every time you have a successful commit

Comment: do you mean CI script? for what platform?

Comment: say there are specific plugins for Jenkins like https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/08/17/code-coverage-api-plugin-1/